# How can I add class for the link based on youtube.com/embed URL andress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, youtube

I have a lightbox plugin, which use lightview class for links.
So the usage looks like this:

```
<a href="https://youtube.com/embed/HPOcZtfjrrU?start=102&autoplay=1" class="lightview">Link for the site</a>
```

I want add this class (lightview) for everylink which started this url:

> https://youtube.com/embed/

This is the important part:
I don't want to add class for links like that:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XtSf8GqrF6Q
Because this url will be embedded on my site.

Comment: For example you have 5 a elements with href="https://youtube.com/embed/" and you want to give this elements a class that is called lightview but those a elements that doesn't have href="https://youtube.com/embed/" you don't want to give a class named lightview is this what you're asking

Comment: Yes absolutly, sorry for the delay :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With jQuery you can select all the elements that have an attribute which start with a given value by using the `[attribute^=value]` selector. Then you would just need to add the `lightview` class to those elements. It is as simple as:

```
$("a[href^='https://youtube.com/embed']").addClass("lightview");
```

Here is a demo:

```js
$("a[href^='https://youtube.com/embed']").addClass("blue");
```

```css
a {
    display:block;
    color:red;
}

a.blue {
    color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://youtube.com/embed/HPOcZtfjrrU?start=102&autoplay=1">Video with right link</a>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XtSf8GqrF6Q">Video without right link</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Link to Google</a>
<a href="https://youtube.com/embed/HPOcZtfjrrU?start=102&autoplay=1">Antoher video with right link</a>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Another wrong link</a>
```

Comment: Very elegant syntax choice, I've to admit... +1 for you.

Comment: Thank you it's working, only need to do with this code:
**Put on document.ready**, becouse myscript place in the body.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jquery to retrieve the `a` tags and for each tag if `href` starts with `https://youtube.com/embed/`a class is added:

```
$(function(){
  $("a").each(function(ix, el){
    if(el.href.match("^https://youtube.com/embed/")) {
      $(el).addClass('lightbox');
    }
  })
});
```

Here a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/gIabIwkC0KXqvSCijMcf).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery can be used to achieve the desired result or it can be done in pure CSS3 as shown below:

```
a[href^='https://youtube.com/embed'] {
color:blue;
}
```

And because it doesn't use any form of JavaScript, it will work regardless of whether the user has JavaScript enabled or not